# How to remove first numbers from column which start with numbers - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column like this

```
1 prova
2 prova 34 bla bla
3 prova 
bla bla
bla 44 bla 
232 bla bla 89 bla
5987 bla bla
```

I woukd like to delete the first numbers from fields.
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
prova
prova 34 bla bla
prova 
bla bla
bla 44 bla 
bla bla 89 bla
bla bla
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can do a regex replacement:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^\\d+\\s*', '') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7b4991a13bb5813aa9fa4799e11bd10).

On earlier versions, we have to do more work.  One approach:

```sql
SELECT col,
       CASE WHEN col REGEXP '^[0-9]'
            THEN SUBSTRING(col, INSTR(col, ' ') + 1)
            ELSE col END AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

And here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a70b62624fc71edbca99015a45aa329) for this second query.